# Align div/text right using inline-flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a few animated links that use `display: inline-flex`. This works fine until I want to align them to the right. I can position to the right using `float: right` but I assume there's a better way?

I've tried `justify-content: flex-end;` which doesn't seem to work with `inline-flex`? I'd be happy to use `display: flex` but that stretches my links out 100% wide which I don't want and I couldn't get anything to work to prevent that.

So I'm a little stuck. Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to resolve this? Feel like I'm missing something obvious. Here's a CodePen showing the link styling...

Link: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/rNjbrYL

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to have all your `<a href="#" class="link">` aligned with each-other on the right inside a box that just contains them ? Or is it something inside those elements ?

Comment: Hey @julien.giband by default left aligned is fine, just some places on the site they will appear to the right so I'd just like to accommodate for that - suppose a wrapper div would do it, thinking about it again? Or old skool float!

Comment: Why are you using `display: inline-flex`. Why not `display: flex`?

Comment: Because if you use flex, the links break and span 100% width of the container - so it breaks the effect/animations!

Comment: @user1406440,  This can be avoided. Replace `display: inline-flex` with `display: flex`, and add `margin-left: auto` and `width: fit-content` to `.link`.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Sorry @Paulie_D, you're right I should've done that. I was thinking because of the 'involved' animations I needed to show the link but I should've include just the high-level code. Will address and keep in mind in future too

Comment: Thanks @user1406440 - `width: fit-content` is a game changer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, we have tried this, you include all links in the div and you make the css for your div :

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them all inside a container with `display: inline-flex`

HTML:

```html
<div class="links-container">

  <a href="#" class="link">
    <span class="link__label">
      We Definitely Don’t Include..
    </span>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="link link--core">
    <span class="link__label">
      Follow Us
    </span>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="link link--core align-right">
    <span class="link__label">
      Align to the Right?
    </span>
  </a>
  
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.links-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

For posterity, the rest of your SCSS

```css
/* Global */

$blue: #0000c3;
$yellow: #f0f10d;

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

/* Link */

.link {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 -12px);
  color: $blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:before {
    background: $yellow;
    content: "";
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    //top: 50%;
    left: -4px;
    //transform: translate(0, -50%);
    width: calc(100% - 28px); // still want 8px for padding
  }
}

.link__label {
  padding: 0 0 0 36px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.16s ease-out;

  &:before,
  &:after {
    background-color: $blue;
    content: "";
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transition: all 0.16s ease-out;
    width: 24px;
  }

  &:after {
    right: -36px;
    left: auto;
  }

  .link:hover & {
    left: -36px;

    &:before {
      transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(-180deg);
    }
  }
}

.link--core {
  clip-path: inset(0 -4px 0 0);
  text-align: right;

  &:before {
    right: -4px;
    left: auto;
  }

  .link__label {
    padding: 0 36px 0 0;

    &:before {
      left: -36px;
    }
    &:after {
      right: 0;
    }
  }

  &:hover {
    .link__label {
      left: 36px;

      &:before {
        transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - not all links needs to appear to the right, I just want the option to make them do that if needed. But I suppose the approach works, I'd just need to wrap the link in a div and apply the alignment to that (or just float)?

Comment: I guess... I'm having trouble figuring out what you want exactly. I suppose you could set a class on that wrapper and change the `align-items` depending on it. Or if you want to set this per-link, you could use `align-self` on the ones you want aligned differently. Float sucks. What you can do with float you can do better otherwise.

Comment: Hey, no I think the solution you can works. Basically I have the links in their default styling but in some places they need to appear 'floated' to the other side of the page. I was planning on using a helper or modifier class to apply when needed - but I think just wrapping the individual link in a div and applying to that works. Think I was overcomplicating it! :)